# Lightbox + Views: can I create a sequence with Next and Prev buttons?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've a view in Drupal and each item has a title and an image in its teaser.

Now.. I want to add a lightbox with next / prev buttons to display all the images in big resolution.

I was wondering if "Next and Prev" functionalities work for the images of each node.

So far I've only used a lightbox to display galleries in multiple CCK fields in a single node. And I'm not sure if the lightbox can detect the images of a specific image field in each node and display them as slideshow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of different Lightbox plugins (I think [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) is the recommended one this month), and they all generally work on the same principle when it comes to slideshows. As long as every image/link has the same `rel` attribute, it doesn't matter where they are on the page: they will be grouped in the same slideshow. Example:

```
<p><a href="pic1.jpg" rel="example1" title="Photo 1">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
<!-- tons of markup here -->
<p><a href="pic2.jpg" rel="example1" title="Photo 2">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
<p><a href="pic3.jpg" rel="example1" title="Photo 3">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
```

So, you'll need to modify the content template (in the case of ImageField) or the field templates (in the case of Views) and add the `rel` grouping tag in.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, doesn't lightbox look for "example1[]" in rel? Or is that shadowbox only?